# Is dimension the only invariant of a vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Given a finite dimensional vector space $V(F)$ the dimension is preserved by any isomorphism from $V(F)$ to another finite dimensional vector space $W(F)$. I cannot think of any other property related to $V(F)$, (such as order of an element when we consider $V$ as an abelian group) that is preserved. Is it correct to say that dimension is the only invariant. Why is that?

**Update based on PavelČoupek's comment:**

It is certainly true that several other properties of vector spaces are preserved under isomorphism as well. So in that sense dimension is not the only invariant. But it is the only invariant in the following sense:

Suppose there is an invariant property $P$ which remains unchanged whenever $V$ undergoes an isomorphic transformation. Then that property $P$ is peculiar to all $n$-dimensional vector spaces (if $\dim V=n$) since all of these are isomorphic. In particular $P$ holds good in $F^n$ and so if one knows the dimension $n$, one can explicit state the instance of $P$ with respect to $F^n$ (for example if the property is cardinality then its instance in $F^n$ will be $|F^n|$). By extension this can be now done in $V$ (for which also we have $|V|=|F^n|$). In this way, the dimension is the invariant from which all other invariants stem from.

Is this correct? Can someone explain it in more mathematical terms?

Comment: I will assume you are talking about finite-dimensional vector spaces (even though it's not really necessary). A little nitpicking comment: you can define any invariants out of the dimension you like, e.g. call a weird-dimension of a vector space $V$ the number $(\mathrm{dim}\,V)^2+3$. Then any isomorphism preserves weird-dimension. More importantly, since having the same dimension is also sufficient for existence of an isomorphism, any kind of invariant you come up with will necessarily be determined by dimension.

Comment: What kind of field is$F$?

Comment: $F$ is any field.

Comment: @PavelČoupek: Will any kind of invariant be determined by the dimension *solely*?

Comment: So, just to clarify, you are asking if among all of the properties which are definable in all the vector spaces $\{V(F):dim(V(F))<\infty,F$ field $\}$, the dimension is the only one which is preserved under isomorphisms? Can you give an example of one of such properties which is not preserved under isomorphisms?

Comment: @Shahab: Well, yes. I mean, maybe not by some nice formula, but in the following sense: Suppose that $V \mapsto \chi(V)$ ($\chi(V) \in S$) is some invariant of $V$, i.e. something that satisfies the property that $\chi(V)=\chi(W)$ whenever $V \simeq W$. Then one has the function $\tilde{\chi}: \mathbb{N} \rightarrow S$ given by $n \mapsto \chi(F^n)$ such that $\chi=\tilde{\chi} \circ \mathrm{dim}$. Thus, the invariant $\chi$ is completely detemined by $\mathrm{dim}$.

Comment: @PavelČoupek: What is $S$?

Comment: @Shahab $S$ is just a set where the values of the invariant $\chi$ live, i.e. I am assuming that the invariant is a "function" (modulo slight set-theoretical problems) from finite-dimensional vector spaces to $S$.

Comment: @PavelČoupek: Thank you. I would strongly suggest that you post your comments as an answer. It will be helpful for other users who read this later.

Comment: Ok. I am way no expert here but consider the following: As you are considering properties definable for every finite vector space over every field, every property you might define will be given in terms of the axioms of vector space. Now, vector space isomorphisms are defined that way so they preserve all of the algebraic structure of vector space. I.e., if we only see $V$ and $W$ as vector spaces then actually we can consider $V=W$ if $V\sim W$. So I'd say that there can't exist a property satisfied by $V$ but not by $W$. I lack the knowledge to express that with rigour though.

Comment: @mathbeing: I am not contesting the fact that there exists no property satisfied by $V$ but not $W$. The question is whether dimension is (essentially) the only property that both $V$ and $W$ commonly enjoy.

Comment: In all examples I can think of $V$ and $W$ have the same cardinality. Is that an invariant?

Comment: I think you are not understanding me. The fact that there exists no property satisfied by $V$ but not by $W$ if $V\simeq W$ implies, given the arbitrariness of $V$ and $W$, that all of the properties we are considering are preserved under isomorphisms.

Comment: Yes, cardinality is an invariant (cardinality is preserved by bijections so particularly by isomorphisms).

Answer (score 2):

It's the only invariant because if the dimensions match you can choose a basis in each and use those equicardinal bases to construct an isomorphism.

Comment: How does this prove that there are no other invariants?

Comment: @Shahab What means "invariant" for you? I think it is something preserved by isomorphisms.  If the field and the dimension determine isomorphism type, then no other information is needed to determine the isomorphism type. In this sense, it is the "only" invariant. Of course, the number "dimension + 17" is another invariant, but it carries the same information.